# Is it possible to use a React-Native library inside my native Java code for Android?

Tags: java, android, react-native, interop

I am currently developing an app in Java for Android. There is a library written for React-Native that I would like to use inside my native code.

I know that it is possible to integrate React-Native with already existing apps. But from what I understood this integration is only possible for Android components such as Activities or Fragments. I do not want to use a new  React-Native Activity inside my Java code, what I want is to use is the types and classes defined in the React-Native library inside my already existing Java activity.

Is this something that is possible ?

I have read a lot of topics on the other way around : using native libraries inside React-Native but I couldn't find anything regarding using React-Native libraries in Java. Would you have any suggestions that would make it possible ?

Comment: By implementing Native Modules you can achieve this https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-intro

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but according to what is written in the documentation you have given, a Native Module is a tool to use native APIs inside Javascript. I want the inverse : to use React-Native libraries inside Java. Or did I wrongly understand the documentation ?

Comment: It's as easy as copying the native code in the react-native library

Comment: Yes exactly, you can find the code in the github.